# Pictures don't appear when display: none is removed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML and JavaScript. There are three pictures and three links. Clicking on one link shows one picture and hides the other two.

When the `display: none` in the CSS is not there, this works fine. But I put `display: none` there because I want the pictures **not** to appear initially. Now, when I click on the links, pictures never appear. Why is that?

HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img1')">show image1</a>
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img2')">show image2</a>
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img3')">show image3</a>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
     <img id="img1" src="berlin.jpg" height="200px"/>
     <img id="img2" src="london.jpg" height="200px"/>
     <img id="img3" src="madrid.jpg" height="200px"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function showImage(id) {
    var images_id = new Array("img1", "img2", "img3");
    for (var i = 0; i < images_id.length; i++) {
        setImageVisible(images_id[i], false);
    }
    setImageVisible(id, true);
}

function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.display = (visible ? '' : 'none');
}
```

CSS

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `elem.style.property`, you are only affecting the `style` attribute. By setting it to `""`, you are removing it from that attribute and letting the stylesheet take effect with its `display:none`.

Try setting it to `block` instead.